# Commutative diagram with non-uniform arrows

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I wrote following program for a commutative diagram.

```
\begin{tikzcd}
0\arrow[r] & M\arrow[r]\arrow[d] & N\arrow[r]\arrow[d] & K\arrow[d]\\
0\arrow[r] & M'\arrow[r]         & N' \arrow[r]        & K' \\
\end{tikzcd}
```

The output is the following.

[image]

> **Q.** If I do not want the $0$ and arrow going at M, and want to put an arrow with end 0 after K, what should be change in commands? I added/removed some natural commands from above program; but it was always creating error. For example, I removed **0\arrow[r]** from first command-line in above commands; but it produced error.

Comment: So you want to add an arrow from 0 to K?

Comment: From K to 0, on right side; and I want to delete arrow towards M' from 0 (below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
  & M\arrow[r]\arrow[d] & N\arrow[r]\arrow[d] & K\arrow[d]\arrow[r] & 0\\
  0\arrow[r] & M'\arrow[r] & N' \arrow[r] & K' \\
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```